# How to use BibTeX references in LyX PhD thesis template

Tags: lyx, templates, lyx-layouts

I am using the kks32 PhD thesis template from here: https://github.com/kks32/PhDThesisLyX

I dont seem to understand how references will work. For example when I am writing a paper, all the related files are in the same folder including the .lyx main file and the bibtex .bib file.

But in the template linked above all the files are in separate folders, each chapter has its own folder and the references has its own folder. I cannot link to the references file from Chapter 1.

Normally I would add the .bib file via Insert >> List >> BibTeX bibliography. Once added the references in the added .bib file they would show up in the Insert >> Citation menu. But that is not the case here, how can I link the .bib file to be used in all the chapters?

Thank you

Comment: Can't you just cut and paste all files from the folders into the main folder?

Comment: By the way, some things have been fied for the usual LaTe version. The LyX template might show some strange behaviour sometimes.

Comment: What you need, I think, is having the master file open at all times. That's how LyX will know what bibliography file is being used. Work on separate chapters by opening them from the master file (right click>edit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is having the master file open at all times. That's how LyX will know what bibliography file is being used. Work on separate chapters by opening them from the master file (right click>edit).